# Closures of Relations

Tags: relations

How to prove that the transitive closure of a symmetric closure of a relation is greater than the symmetric closure of a transitive closure of a relation?

Comment: the only idea i have is that transitive closure of symmetric closure contains reflexive elements but the other one does not necessarily contain reflexive elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essential is here that the symmetric closure of a transitive relation is not necessarily transitive. For instance on positive integers look at the relation $n\mid m$, i.e $n$ divides $m$. The symmetric closure of it is the relation $n\mid m\vee m\mid n$. The numbers $4$ and $12$ are related and so are the numbers $12$ and $6$, but $4$ and $6$ are clearly not.

On the other hand the transitive closure of a symmetric relation is symmetric itself. So if we denote the transitive and symmetric closure of a relation
$R$ respectively by $\tau\left(R\right)$ and $\sigma\left(R\right)$
then we find in $\tau\left(\sigma\left(R\right)\right)$ a transitive
and symmetric relation that contains $\tau\left(R\right)$. This leads
to $\sigma\left(\tau\left(R\right)\right)\subset\tau\left(\sigma\left(R\right)\right)$.

In $\sigma\left(\tau\left(R\right)\right)$ we recognize a relation
that contains $\sigma\left(R\right)$ but is not necessarily transitive.
If it is not transitive then $\sigma\left(\tau\left(R\right)\right)$
must be a proper subset of $\tau\left(\sigma\left(R\right)\right)$.

Comment: "This leads to σ(τ(R))⊂τ(σ(R))." cant get this part....

Comment: $\sigma\left(\tau\left(R\right)\right)$ is the 'smallest'
symmetric relation that contains $\tau\left(R\right)$ and
can be defined as the intersection of all symmetric relations that
contain $\tau\left(R\right)$. This way it is a subset of all symmetric
relations that contain $\tau\left(R\right)$. One of them is $\tau\left(\sigma\left(R\right)\right)$.